# How to compile Discount C-library?

Tags: c, markdown, discount

I want to use the [Discount](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/) C-library to convert [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) text into HTML. I have already successfully compiled and installed the library (version 2.1.3).

I tried to compile this code

```
#include <mkdio.h>
int main(void)
{
 FILE *in, *out;
 MMIOT *doc;

 in = fopen("sample.md", "r");
 out = fopen("out.html", "w");

 doc = mdk_in(in, 0);
 markdown(doc, out, 0);

 ...
}
```

*Explanation*: `mkd_in()`reads the input file `in`into the library working-type `MMIOT doc` and markdown() should convert `doc` to HTML and writes is to the `out` file.

with the command `gcc -Wall -lmarkdown -o FILE FILE.c` and I always get the following output:

```
undefined reference to `mkd_in(_IO_FILE*, unsigned int)'
undefined reference to `markdown(void*, _IO_FILE*, unsigned int)'
```

**Note**: I've run the configuration tool of Discount with the `--shared` option to build a dynamic library. Default is a static library but with that I've got the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
gcc -Wall -o FILE FILE.c -lmarkdown
```

The placement of `-l` is significant in that many linkers will only use libraries to satisfy unresolved references if they exist *at the time when the `-l` is parsed.* This can cause all sorts of problems with circular dependencies, for example.

Where you have it originally, those functions aren't unresolved since you haven't yet compiled `FILE.c`. When you *do* compile `FILE.c`, there's no `-l` following that point to satisfy the references.

From the `gcc` man-page:

> Order does matter when you use several options of the same kind; for example, if you specify -L more than once, the directories are searched in the order specified.  Also, the placement of the -l option is significant.

And, later, under `-l`:

> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified.  Thus, foo.o -lz bar.o searches library z after file foo.o but before bar.o.  If bar.o refers to functions in z, those functions may not be loaded.

Comment: I have the same exact issue as the original poster, but your answer didn't help - any idea why? I'm going crazy!

Comment: @Vittorio, if it's the _exact_ same problem, the answer will work. Your best bet is to ask another question with the full details, specifically those that are different, otherwise it'll be closed as a duplicate. By asking a question you get the full resources of SO looking into your problem rather than just me :-)

Comment: I fixed it! Added `extern "C"` in the header include.